# Whenever I log out or switch user my resolution is incorrect for a few minutes

Tags: windows-7

Around 3-5 monts ago I had a 1280x1024 resolution monitor. This one worked fine, but obviously it was too small for todays standards, so I bought a new one. The current one I'm using is a 1920x1080 monitor. This monitor has a pretty annoying problem however.

Whenever I switch user or log out to let my brother use the computer it, the computer for some reason thinks I have a 1600x1200 resolution monitor. There is only one way to change this, and that is by using a program called "AMD catalyst control center" (I have an AMD graphics card btw). This allows me to pick a 1080p resolution, however, it only allows me to run it at 29 hz. So whenever I pick the 1080p option this way the screen "flashes" really quickly, which hurts my eyes. The only real way to fix this is to turn off the computer and wait around 5-10 minutes. This isn't really a good fix since it seems random how long I have to wait, and if I boot my computer during this time the "timer" seems to reset.

I don't know how to check my other specs, but I know I have a AMD phenom II X4 965 processor. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing your graphics card driver and related programs like the catalyst control center.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, I'm not that much of a super user :c

Comment: I don't have a Windows 7 machine in front of me, so I can't give you the exact click sequence, but there's a control panel that lets you uninstall programs. Uninstall any AMD/Catalyst programs that relate to graphics. (Be careful, don't remove any other AMD hardware drivers if you have them for things like your disk controller.)

Comment: So I now know how to uninstall it, but how would I reinstall it? The uninstaller doesn't offer me to do so.

Comment: Download the driver from AMD's web site and then run the installer.

Comment: That didn't help. It still sometimes messes up the resolution while loggin out or switching user, but it can sometimes also do this if you do nothing at all. However it only seems to do this on certain sessions on the computer.